# Objective C method with multiple NSStrings as argument

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I need to make init method with multiple NSStrings as argument.

Assume it looks like:
'-(id) initWithSomething: (NSString *) things, nil;'

How to recognize number of strings and write them into array ?

Regards

Comment: Do you want a variable number of arguments (being able to call the function with any number of `NSString`s) or just multiple arguments (only being able to call it with a predefined number of `NSString`s)?

Answer (score 4):

Use a variadic method:

```
//Interface
-(id) initWithSomething:(NSString*) arg1, ...;
//Implementation
-(id) initWithSomething:(NSString*) arg1, ... {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, firstObject);
    id obj;
    for (obj = firstObject; obj != nil; obj = va_arg(args, id))
        //Do stuff with each object.
    va_end(args);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What you want is a [Variadic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function#Variadic_functions_in_C.2C_Objective-C.2C_C.2B.2B.2C_and_D).

Answer (score 0):

Basic objective-C syntax is as follows:

```
-(type)methodNameTakesInput:(type)param1 andMoreInput:(type)param2
```

So you can do

```
-(id)initWithString:(NSString *)str andOtherThing:(NSObject *)obj
```

Alternately, you could just pass the array you want:

```
-(id)initWithStuff:(NSArray *)arrayOfStuff
```

and fill the array as you normally would:

```
NSArray *arrayOfStuff = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Strings!", @"More strings!", nil];
```